# Signing Algorithm in identity server

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, authorization, identityserver4

I am using Duende Identity Server, and I want to specify the signing algorithm for the access token of a particular API resource. By default, Duende Identity Server uses RSA 256 for signing the access tokens. However, I'm unsure how to set a specific algorithm for the access tokens.

Additionally, I noticed a table called "Key," but I don't fully understand its purpose and utility in the context of Duende Identity Server. Could you please provide more information or clarification about the "Key" table?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm only familiar with IdentityServer4, I haven't yet updated my own organization to IdentityServer6, so if you're using a later version be sure to verify my answer against your IS assemblies, perhaps using ILSpy).

> I am using Duende Identity Server, and I want to specify the signing algorithm for the `access_token` of a particular API resource. By default, Duende Identity Server uses `RSA256` for signing the access tokens. However, I'm unsure how to set a specific algorithm for the access tokens.

- Before you can use an alternative algorithm to `RSA256`, such as `ES256`, you need to ensure your IdentityServer has a suitable certificate and private-key for the new algorithm you want to use.

  - You do this by adding your certificates (or other *key-material*) to `IIdentityServerBuilder` during `Startup`, using the `IdentityServerBuilderExtensionsCrypto.AddSigningCredential` method; you may need to explicitly specify a `IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.$algorithm` enum value too.
- Then update your `IResourceStore` or `ApiResource` objects such that the `ApiResource.AllowedAccessTokenSigningAlgorithms` includes the new algorithm.

  - Do not confuse `ApiResource.AllowedAccessTokenSigningAlgorithms` with `Client.AllowedIdentityTokenSigningAlgorithms`. Ignore any `Client` settings for now.
- Your RPs will need to specifically support the algorithm you're specifying; This *should* not impact any Clients (unless the RP itself is also a Client) because Clients are meant to treat `access_token` values as opaque strings and to never inspect them (e.g. with a JWT library); if a Client wants to see Claims values they're meant to use the `id_token` which will use a different signing algorithm (specified in IS4's `Client.AllowedIdentityTokenSigningAlgorithms`).

---

For example, if you want to use ES256 then you'll want something like this:

**Your IdentityServer's Startup.cs**

```cs
IIdentityServerBuilder idSrvBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer( ... );

X509Certificate2 yourRsaCertificate = ...
X509Certificate2 yourEcdsaCertificate = ...

// Add the standard/basic/traditional RS256 cert:
_ = idSrvBuilder.AddSigningCredential( certificate: yourRsaCertificate, signingAlgorithm: "RS256" );

// Add ES256 as an alternative for services that support it:
ECDsa eccPrivate = yourEcdsaCertificate.GetECDsaPrivateKey();
ECDsaSecurityKey eccKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey( eccPrivate )
{
    KeyId = "<your key-id here>"
};

_ = idSrvBuilder.AddSigningCredential( eccKey, IdentityServer4.IdentityServerConstants.ECDsaSigningAlgorithm.ES256 );
```

**Your IdentityServer's Resource store**:

(This code assumes you're using immutable `ApiResource` objects in-memory)

```cs
private static readonly ApiResource _myFirstApiResourceUsingRsa256 = new ApiResource()
{
    // etc
};

private static readonly ApiResource _myOtherApiResourceUsingES256 = new ApiResource()
{
    AllowedAccessTokenSigningAlgorithms = { "ES256" },
    // etc
};
```

Your RPs *may or may not* need special configuration to work (other than ensuring that your RP's JWT-processing-middleware actually supports ES256); but as far as I've experienced it should *just work* because the RP will automagically get the public part of the ES256 key directly from the IdentityServer IdP (assuming the RP can directly contact the IdP).

I'd like to restate the important detail that this all assumes that Clients (which are not RPs themselves) do not attempt to inspect the `access_token` themselves, e.g. to verify the token or to extract Claims - otherwise changing the signing algorithm might break the Client (which may be desirable if you feel like *punishing* a bad Client that isn't using `id_token` like they're meant to).

If your RP is also a Client itself (and let's ignore [`delegation` grants](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html) for now) then it should still continue to work just fine - *but* you may need to update the `Client.AllowedIdentityTokenSigningAlgorithms` to specify `ES256` if the RP also requires ES256 instead of RSA256 for `id_token` signatures.

---

> Additionally, I noticed a table called "Key," but I don't fully understand its purpose and utility in the context of Duende Identity Server. Could you please provide more information or clarification about the "Key" table?

- You'll only see the `Key` (or `Keys`) table if you're using the `Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Storage` package to handle the DB for you.

  - There is no requirement to use EF/database storage for Keys (e.g. my own projects often use Azure Key Vault, or the local filesystem).
- This table is used by `Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Stores.SigningKeyStore` to store keys and certificates.

  - So if your project uses the DB for storing keys and certificates, then ensure the `Keys` table contains a valid key/certificate for the algorithm you want to use.